# Accordion only once open + Cookie for last opened

Tags: jquery, cookies

Trying to use the cookie, to see what accordion was last opened + the option that only one accordion at a time can be opened. Each function itselfs works - but together not. Is it e.preventDefault() that is causing the trouble?

```
$("#accordion").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            var active = $("#accordion .in").attr('id');
            $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup', active);
            //  alert(active);
        });
        $("#accordion").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $.removeCookie('activeAccordionGroup');
        });
        var last = $.cookie('activeAccordionGroup');
        if (last != null) {
            //remove default collapse settings
            $("#accordion .panel-collapse").removeClass('in');
            //show the account_last visible group
            $("#" + last).addClass("in");
        }

        $('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
            if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
                e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();
            }
```

Comment: Instead of using cookies, try using local storage.

Comment: provide Js fiddle if possible.

Comment: @Samir I tried over local, but it didnt save after I went back later.

Comment: @RemS it is hard, because it loads a bunch of Bootstrap